# Como funciona a execução do C# no universal app?

Tags: c#, uwp

Comecei a estudar a universal app do Windows 10 e vi que o modo de execução é diferente do Win32 ou .Net, já que utiliza o WinRT que faz chamadas diretamente ao kernel do sistema, deixando linguagens como c#, vb e js no nível de c++, pelo menos foi o que eu li.

O que eu queria saber é se o C# precisa do .NET ou de alguma máquina virtual para funcionar ou ele utiliza apenas a API WinRT para executar as funções?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compilação de um UWP pode ser feita usando a criação de código nativo, que causa um ótimo desempenho no app, porém o tempo de compilação aumenta significativamente, só sendo recomendado para criar a versão final de sua aplicação devido à demora.
E não, não é necessária máquina virtual nem nada do tipo, na compilação de código nativo tudo é feito a nível de máquina.